# Android 5.0: howto change Overview Screen Task Title background color

Tags: android, android-theme, android-5.0-lollipop

The new Android 5.0 Lollipop [Overview Screen](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/recents.html) features each App's Task with a screenshot and a (by default) grey title bar.

Some Lollipop Apps (For example the new Play Store) use different colours. How can the colour of the Overview Screen title background be changed?

[image: Android Overview Screen, Creative Commons Attribution 2.5]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In general, if you're targeting Material then you should set `colorPrimary` (action bar, recents), `colorPrimaryDark` (status bar), and `colorAccent` (check boxes, progress bars, etc) in your theme.

That said, you can dynamically change the recents color to be something else using:

```
TaskDescription taskDesc = new TaskDescription(myTitle, myIcon, myColor);
myActivity.setTaskDescription(taskDesc);
```

Comment: I keep getting an error that the primaryColor needs to be Opaque.  I have verified it is indeed opaque.  Could it some how be conflicting with my theme or when I call the code?

Comment: SOLVED - I had colorPrimary not set to Alpha 255 which caused the issue. It seems to use that first before setting your custom color.

Comment: @Codeversed Good rule of thumb with Android is to add FF to the start of every colour code your use (or another value if you don't full 100% alpha).

Comment: I have set theme in my app with colorPrimaryDark,colorPrimary,colorAccent  style color. I have tried your code also. Its works fine with pain color I mean without Opacity But when I added alpha colors it will carsh If I use "4DFFFFFF" color app crash. Work fine with "FFFFFF" color

Comment: @alanv Is there any help for this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161776/android-material-theme-alpha-color-issue